# Ordering List by a specific character (Java 8)

Tags: java, list, sorting, java-8, comparator

I have the following List:

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Watermelon", "Peach"));
```

I need to order it with this condition:

1. In the first place, the ones that contains the char "o" or "O"
2. Then, the rest of them.

The result should be:

```
Orange, Watermelon, Apple, Banana, Peach
```

How can I do it in Java 8?

Comment: You can use `Collections.sort` with a self-implemented Comparator. ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a Comparator chain.

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                               "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Watermelon", "Peach"));
fruits.sort(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.contains("O") && !s.contains("o"))
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
System.out.println(fruits.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

The first comparator looks at whether the string contains an O making the ones which do go first, and the second comparator uses natural ordering.

Note: `Boolean.TRUE.compareTo(Boolean.FALSE) > 0` so to make the strings which contain an O go first I flip this with a `!`

This prints

```
Orange, Watermelon, Apple, Banana, Peach
```

NOTE: In this case, the `new ArrayList<>( ... )` isn't needed as `sort` doesn't change the number of elements, just re-arranges them.

---

EDIT: Based on @Holger's suggestion.

If a stable sort is preferred, i.e. leave the order as it was at much as possible.

```
List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList(
        "Watermelon", "Peach", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple");
fruits.sort(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.contains("O") && !s.contains("o")));
System.out.println(fruits.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

prints

```
Watermelon, Orange, Peach, Banana, Apple
```

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no requirement that “the rest of them” is sorted by natural order in the question. So you can simply use `Comparator.comparing(s -> !s.toUpperCase().contains("O"))`, to just move those with an O to the front and keep their relative order as-is. An alternative would be `fruits.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pattern.compile("(?i)o").asPredicate().negate() ::test));` which avoids creating uppercase copies of all strings for each comparison. This may pay off for larger lists and/or larger strings.

Comment: @Holger compiling a Pattern would need to be cached or it would be many times more expensive.  I guess I don't rely on the use of a comparator being stable as it depends on context e.g. for a TreeSet it would be very different. The question could suggest a stable sort is preferred.

Comment: The `Pattern` is only compiled once for the entire operation. Of course, if you perform this operation multiple times you may consider keeping the pattern, but that applies to the entire `Comparator` as well. You may also reduce the costs of the pattern initialization using `Pattern.compile("o", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)` instead. But anyway, for such a trivial pattern, the preparation is not more expensive than copying a string, which the other comparator does two time per comparison (and there are about n×log n comparisons in the worst case)…